# Unable to play video from raw folder

Tags: android, media-player

I'm facing a strange problem in my application .
Media player is unable to play video from raw folder but it plays the same video from sdcard.

But if I take another video, it's easily played from the raw folder.

Thanks,
Vikas

### Code

```
mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://<package name>/raw/video1"));
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);
mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(this); 
mVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
mediaController.setEnabled(true);
mVideoView.requestFocus();
mVideoView.start();
```

Comment: do you mean an external media player cannot play a video from within your application raw folder? try and copy it to a public folder.

Comment: Do you means that the same video is not playing from raw folder but its playing from sdcard?? There is the problem in the URI mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://<package name>/+R.raw.video_name")) .

Comment: yes same video is not playing from raw.

Comment: no i have some some video and I reside in raw folder but when I am trying to play these video via video view (MideaPlayer) it gives error but when I put same video in sdcard and set videopath(<sdcard>) then it playing

Comment: I understand can you make available this video file or some part of code for us.?

Comment: you just have something wrong in your code. post it.

Comment: hmm actually I have used same code for both only difference is its path. but for your convenient here is the code::

`mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://<package name>/raw/video1"));
   mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);
   mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(this);
   
   mVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
   mediaController.setEnabled(true);
   mVideoView.requestFocus();
   mVideoView.start();
`

Comment: @vky : did you used this Uri.parse("android.resource://<package name>/+R.raw.video_name") this URI??

Comment: yes I tried with both uri 
1)Uri.parse("android.resource://<package name>/raw/video1")
2)Uri.parse("android.resource://<package name>/+R.raw.video_name")

Answer (score 3):

See this question :

[Playing .MP4 video from raw resource folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944555/playing-mp4-video-from-raw-resource-folder)

As it appears, the Uri should contain the id (R.raw._your_video_) rather than the file name

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://[package]/"+R.raw.[video_resid]);
```

Comment: I tried but same error..
 02-29 16:10:17.554: E/MediaPlayer(6351): Unable to to create media player
02-29 16:10:17.554: D/MediaPlayer(6351): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
02-29 16:10:17.558: E/MediaPlayer(6351): error (1, -2147483648)
02-29 16:10:17.613: E/MediaPlayer(6351): Error (1,-2147483648)
02-29 16:10:17.613: D/VideoView(6351): Error: 1,-2147483648

Comment: also I tried with other video so it gives 


02-29 16:13:26.542: W/AudioSystem(6351): AudioFlinger server died!
02-29 16:13:26.542: W/IMediaDeathNotifier(6351): media server died
02-29 16:13:26.542: E/MediaPlayer(6351): error (100, 0)
02-29 16:13:26.542: E/MediaPlayer(6351): Error (100,0)
02-29 16:13:26.542: D/VideoView(6351): Error: 100,0

Comment: Just to be sure, you did replace [package] by the actual package name declared in the manifest, right?

Comment: yes package is same and one thing more when I put same video in internal memory and use this path "/data/data/<package name>/files/video.mp4" it also played the video.