# Android: how to play video from assets?

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I am making an application in which I have to show video from assets folder in a **Fragment**. Can anyone help me do this? Do I need to use VideoView in XML?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to play videos in android from assets folder or raw folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028717/how-to-play-videos-in-android-from-assets-folder-or-raw-folder)

Comment: Yes it is duplicate but do check the link again none of the code is working

Comment: have a look at this issue 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746361/i-want-to-play-a-video-from-my-assets-or-raw-folder

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Instead of accessing from assests,You must copy the video into your project's res/raw folder.
Create raw folder under res folder.
It must be in a supported format (3gp, wmv, mp4 ) and named with lower case, numerics, underscores and dots in its filename likewise:video_file.mp4.

```
VideoView view = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video_file;
view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
view.start();
```

Comment: Your activity extends Fragment or FragmentActivity.Pls Check this.

Comment: Hello,I have used VideoView to play video from raw folder, but video is not played in lower version below 2.3. It shows me error "Video cannot be played" please guide me where is the problem,as video plays in other versions.

Comment: Hey Nidhi, what is format of the video? Can u pls check the video formats supported below 2.3. Otherwise above example works perfectly to play video from asset folder

Comment: try this link for mp4 in asset directory  http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/video-cropping-with-texture-view/21

Answer (score 3):

```
VideoView view = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video_file;
view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
view.start();
```

It's AkashG's code, but I remember that R here is not from the Android class.
It's from your own project.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the MediaItem to play a video from assets

```
    val playerView = view.findViewById<StyledPlayerView>(R.id.player)

    val player = ExoPlayer.Builder(context!!).build()
    
    val videoUri = Uri.parse("asset:///test.mp4")
    val item = MediaItem.fromUri(videoUri)

    player.addMediaItem(item)
    playerView.player = player

    player.prepare()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have already suffered from same problem, u should prefer project's res/raw folder instead of assets. Create raw folder under res folder. Save video file in a supported format *(3gp, wmv, mp4 )* and named with *lowercase, numerics, underscores and dots* in its filename *likewise:filename.3gp* into the raw folder.

```
VideoView videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);

String uriPath = "android.resource://your application package name/raw/your 
wmv/mp4/3gp file in res/raw path without extension";

videoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uriPath));

videoview.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to convert your video into the **InputStream** and then save it to the user's internal storage, then display it and delete that file when the video is finished.

```
try{
     String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+APP_NAME()+"/videos/"+ls+"/" ;
     InputStream input = getAssets().open("vid/dal.mp4");
     String name = System.currentTimeMillis() +".mp4";
     File f = new File(path);
     f.mkdirs();
     int size = input.available();

     FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File(path+name));
     byte data[] = new byte[4096];
     long total = 0;
     int count;
     while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
          output.write(data, 0, count);
          total += count;
          if (size <= total) {
              break;
          }
     }
     output.flush();
     output.close();
     input.close();

     //Toast.makeText(VideoPlayer.this , "file created !" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     Uri uri = Uri.parse(path+name) ;

     videoView.setVideoURI(uri);

     videoview.start();

}cath(Exception e){
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Playing Video(sample.mp4) present in res/ raw folder, along with the Media Controller

// Import Statements

```
import android.widget.VideoView;
import android.widget.MediaController;

public class youractiviy extends Activity {

private VideoView videoView;
private MediaController mediaController;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 // Your Startup code
 videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
 videoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sample); 
 mediaController = new MediaController(TestActivity.this);
 mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
 videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
 videoView.start();

}
}
```

// XML Code

```
<VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```