# android play a video from res/raw

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, playback

I want to play a video from res/raw in android here is my code:

```
public class CreditsActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.creditslayout);
            VideoView v = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
            v.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://test.test.test/raw/maincredits"));
            v.start();
    }
}
```

But I hear only the sound of video. And the emulator doesn't show the video itself the size of file is 2.8 MB.

Comment: I can hear just the sound of video. and the emulator doesn't show the video the size of file is 2.8 MB

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to play video from raw folder (VideoView)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609219/trying-to-play-video-from-raw-folder-videoview)

Comment: @MohammadMobayen : set height/width for VideoView

Comment: @MohammadMobayen Please accept Answers so other people may helpful

Answer (score 3):

Try below code :

```
public class CreditsActivity extends Activity{

        @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.creditslayout);
                VideoView v = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
                v.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video_file));
                v.start();

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://test.test.test/"+R.raw.[video_resid]);    
v.setVideoURI(uri);
```

Answer (score 1):

try `Uri.parse("android.resource://test.test.test/" + R.raw.yourVideoName)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
       // trailer_final is the video name

      String fileName = "android.resource://"+ getPackageName()+"/raw/trailer_final";

      VideoView mvideo = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.playVideo);

      mvideo.setVideoPath(fileName);

      MediaController controller = new MediaController(this);

      mvideo.setMediaController(controller);

      mvideo.requestFocus();

      mvideo.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
VideoView view = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video_file;
view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
view.start();
```

Just pass the name of the video residing in the raw folder under res of the project.

Comment: check this out-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356601/androidplay-video-from-assets/11356700#11356700

Answer (score 0):

The emulator doesn't show the video. I had this problem on a project. We tried it on an actual device and it played perfectly. Try to play it on actual device. It will likely work.