# How to bundle video with application

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have seen a lot of tutorials showing how to play a video from a URL but I want to be able to play a video that I put in my application before I build it.

Is it possible?

Also for those saying that my app will become too big, the video is only 267kb.

Answer (score 0):

Any files in the `assets` or `res\raw` folders are bundled within the APK.

Answer (score 0):

as @F43nd1r suggested, copy the folder into the `assets` folder but before you try playing it from there, you have to copy it to device's storage.

Check this:

[Android: how to play video from assets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356601/android-how-to-play-video-from-assets?answertab=active#tab-top)